# How to setup circleci with environment config files

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, circleci-2.0

I have a front-end build and deploy that I want to run on circleci with node. The deploy part needs a config file with api keys and passwords which I don't want to store in git. How do I add a config file to my build?

Answer (score 1):

*disclaimer: Developer Evangelist at CircleCI.*

The CircleCI config file itself would be stored in Git. API keys, passwords, and secrets you'd store in [private environment variables](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/#adding-environment-variables-in-the-app) via the CircleCI UI.

Comment: Not the circleci config itself, another config file needed by a node package for the deploy process

Comment: Same idea. If it's small enough, base64 encode and store in private environment variable. If it's not, store only the secret bits or encrypt the file and store the key in a private environment variable.